# How to resolve "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error. tSQL, Microsoft Server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help. I keep getting a **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"** error right before the `INSERT` statement. I can see that the problem stems from either the `[nowtime]` or the `[a_Timestamp]` because of the datatypes, and I have to convert them to the same type. However somehow I can't get it to work no matter what I try. In the background `[a_Timestamp]` is `CHAR(13)` and `@nowtime` is `CONVERT(time,CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 108))`.

The **purpose of the full query** is to monitor a DBs past 1, 5 and 10 seconds of data, so the time operations are vital and must be quick. If you need more of the code (or all of it) im happy to provide!

```
CREATE TABLE #base
      (
         [date]       CHAR(8),
         [a_MemberId] CHAR(5),
         [a_Timestamp]CHAR(8),
         [nowTime]    TIME
      )
    INSERT INTO #base
                ([date],
                 [a_MemberId],
                 [a_Timestamp],
                 [nowTime])
    SELECT [date]                         AS [date],
           [a_MemberId]                   AS [a_MemberId],
           SUBSTRING([a_Timestamp],0,7)   AS [timeStamp],
           @nowTime                       AS [nowTime] 
    FROM   [ObserverDB].[dbo].[onti_ord] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE  [date] = @TodaysDateTEST AND [a_Timestamp] < @nowTime
    ORDER  BY [date]
```

Comment: `@TodaysDateTEST` is `CHAR(8)`

Comment: then problem in where clause condition `[date] = @TodaysDateTEST` they are not type compatible, you need to convert  `@TodaysDateTEST` in proper date format

Comment: Post some sample data for analysis

Comment: @JaydipJ but `[date]` is treated as `CHAR(8)` as well in the underlying table. I sadly am not allowed change anything about the orig. table since it's not my DB, so I have to find a workaround. Does it make sense to convert all `CHAR` dates to proper `DATE` formats at the very beginning and then deal with it from there on?

Comment: @G2M, SQL Server is well known for finding its own order of execution. Your *at the very beginning* is not binding for SQL Server. Best do the conversion in the place where you need it. And please show some of your actual date and time strings to see the format in which they are stored!

Comment: @G2M Yes it makes sense to convert your char date values to proper date formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably culture related. Your string is converted implicitly and your culture does not fit to the stored format. It is always a bad idea to store date and/or time values as text.

There is only one sure format: ISO8601 which means (one of many examples)

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ttt (e.g. 2016-08-17T13:11:23)
```

In this line you are comparing your values. Obviously one of them is treated as string and one as date-time value

```
WHERE  [date] = @TodaysDateTEST AND [a_Timestamp] < @nowTime
```

You must make sure (by using `CONVERT` [(details here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with the proper format number), that a date and/or time value is converted to string exactly to the same format as your strings stored (sargable, therefore faster), or to convert your stored values to real date and/or time values and compare them type safe (much cleaner).

Of course the advise should be: Change the database to store this propperly, but - as you stated in comment - you have to deal with this...

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks that's the missing piece! :)